# Multiple definition of yylex

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, lex

I have tried the below lex and yacc file and it seems like there are multiple definitions for many functions like yylex, yyrestart, and many more. I tried several ways and the online materials but could not resolve it. Any help could be appreciated.

try1.l file is as below,

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
int linenum=1;
int temp_int;
%}
%%

\n     {linenum++;}

[\t ]         /* skip spaces */;
\/\/[^\n]*    /* ignore comments */;

"+"     {return '+';}
"-"     {return '-';}
"*"     {return '*';}
"/"     {return '/';}
")"     {return ')';}
"("     {return '(';}

[0-9]+   {sscanf(yytext, "%d", &temp_int);
          yylval.int_val = temp_int;
          return INT;}

.  {printf("LEX: unknown input string found in line %d \n", linenum);
    abort();}
%%

int yywrap(void) {return 1;}
```

try1.y file as below,

```
/* Put new code here */

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


extern int linenum;
%}


/* define all types of variables and terminals */  

%union{
  int int_val;
}

/* define the individual types of variables and terminals */

%token <int_val> INT   
%type <int_val> expr



/* assign priorities to operators in order to 
   avoid shift/reduce conflicts (grammar ambiguities) */

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%left UMINUS


/* the start variable of your program */

%start program


/* The main Grammar with its actions */

%%

program : expr        {printf("Expr value = %d \n", $1);}
        | error       {printf("YACC: syntax error near line %d \n", linenum);
                       abort();}
        ;

expr :'('expr')'        {$$ = $2;}  
     | expr '+' expr    {$$ = $1 + $3;}
     | expr '-' expr    {$$ = $1 - $3;}
     | expr  '*' expr   {$$ = $1 * $3;}
     | expr '/' expr    {$$ = $1 / $3;}
     | '-' expr  %prec UMINUS  {$$ = -$2;}
     | INT              {$$ = $1;}
     ;
      

%%

/* link lex code */

#include "lex.yy.c"

/* insert additional code here */

int main(){
    return yyparse();
}

int yyerror(char *s) {fprintf(stderr, "%s \n",s);}
```

The output is as below,

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screen-shots of error logs, they are non-searchable.

Comment: Sure thanks for your info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing this problem because the source code for the lexical analyser is being included twice.

When using both lex & yacc (or flex and bison), the generated compiler (the yacc output) typically `#include`s the generated lexical analyser source.

You can see this in your `try1.y` and the output `try1.tab.c` code:

```
/* link lex code */

#include "lex.yy.c"

/* insert additional code here */
```

So either remove that manually from the `try1.tab.c`, or do not compile the `lex.yy.c` along with the `try1.tab.c`.

Probably just:

```
$ flex try1.l
$ bison -d try1.y
$ gcc -g -Wall try1.tab.c -o try1.exe
```

Will get you going.